# How do I open an URL from a RecyclerView in a Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, url, android-recyclerview, hyperlink, fragment

I have a list of items in a RecyclerView that is in a Fragment, and I am trying to make it open an URL by clicking on a certain item. For example, if I click on the first item, it should redirect me to url1, but if I click on the second, it should redirect to url2.

I have seen solutions for recyclerviews in main activity, but those don't seem work in Fragments.

This is **DietAdapter.kt**

```
class DietAdapter(val dietList: List<Diet>): RecyclerView.Adapter<DietAdapter.DietViewHolder>(){

inner class DietViewHolder(val itemBinding: ListitemBinding)
    :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
    fun bindItem(diet:Diet){
        itemBinding.titleImage.setImageResource(diet.titleImage)
        itemBinding.tvHeading.text = diet.heading
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DietViewHolder {
    return DietViewHolder(ListitemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DietViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val diet = dietList[position]
    holder.bindItem(diet)

    holder.itemBinding.rowList.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("<add url here>"))
        requireContext().startActivity(browserIntent) //<--here the requireContext throws "no value passed for parameter 'provider' "
    })

}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dietList.size
}
```

}

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't work any differently whether it's in a Fragment's layout vs. an Activity's layout. The only difference for your task above would be the content of the click listener that you pass to your adapter. In the case of the Fragment, you would use `requireContext().startActivity()` instead of just `startActivity()`. Or if you're not exposing a listener property from your adapter, you can pass a Context to the adapter instead and start activities from the adapter. (that's a worse solution in terms of logical encapsulation though.

Comment: I'll update the question to show the code I have so far, the requireContext() needs a parameter now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The quick and dirty solution:

Add a Context property to your constructor:

```
class DietAdapter(val context: Context, val dietList: List<Diet>) //...
```

and when you create the adapter in your fragment, pass `requireContext()` as the parameter for `context`. Now you can use `context.startActivity()` inside your adapter's click listener(s).

---

#### The solution with proper [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns):

Your adapter should not be internally responsible for navigation. That is a job for the higher level object, the Fragment. Trying to have the adapter reach into the Fragment to do things that a Fragment should do makes your code more convoluted. Instead, the adapter should expose a listener property (changes from your code are commented):

```
class DietAdapter(
    val dietList: List<Diet>,
    var onItemClick: (Diet)->Unit = {}  // Added this
): RecyclerView.Adapter<DietAdapter.DietViewHolder>(){
    
    inner class DietViewHolder(val itemBinding: ListitemBinding)
        :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
        fun bindItem(diet:Diet){
            itemBinding.titleImage.setImageResource(diet.titleImage)
            itemBinding.tvHeading.text = diet.heading
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DietViewHolder {
        return DietViewHolder(ListitemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DietViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val diet = dietList[position]
        holder.bindItem(diet)
    
        // Changed this:
        holder.itemBinding.rowList.setOnClickListener { onItemClick(diet) }
    
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dietList.size
    }

}
```

Then, the fragment is where you decide what to do with clicked items:

```
val dietAdapter = DietAdapter(theDataList) { diet ->
    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("<add url here>"))
    requireContext().startActivity(browserIntent) 
}
binding.myRecyclerView.adapter = dietAdapter
```

Comment: Thank you! With your help I also figured out how I could set multiple urls. Cheers!